# Access chromes window.performance from Protractor test

Tags: memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools, protractor

I would like to track memory usage in a Protractor test by accessing the

```
window.performance.memory object.
```

I have added the necessary flag to to the protractor.conf.js  by adding

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        args: ['enable-memory-info'],
```

And I can access the memory object via the above command. My question is how to access the window object from the protractor test itsself?

I have tried:

```
element(by.id('window')).then(function(win){
        theWindow = win;
        console.log("Set the window: " + theWindow);
        var mem = win.performance.memory;
        console.log("Memory: " + mem);
```

but this selector seems to be unavailable with this error:

```
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.id("window")
```

What options do I have in Protractor to access the browser window ? I have also tried the advice given here [Access window object / browser scope from protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26102132/access-window-object-browser-scope-from-protractor), but had no success in getting the memory object.

Answer (score 4):

A slight modification to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26102132/access-window-object-browser-scope-from-protractor) post's code seems to do the trick:

```
function measurememory() {
    browser.driver.executeScript(function () {
        return window.performance.memory;
    }).then(function (result) {
        console.log("MemoryInfo: jsHeapSizeLimit : " + result.jsHeapSizeLimit);
        console.log("MemoryInfo: usedJSHeapSize : " + result.usedJSHeapSize);
        console.log("MemoryInfo: totalJSHeapSize : " + result.totalJSHeapSize);

    });
}
```